# Has n^2*|sin(n)| limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, gn.general-topology, limits-and-convergence, open-problems

Is there any sub-sequence $n_k$ of natural numbers such as $\lim(n_k^2|\sin(n_k)|) = 0$ ? when $k$ tends to infinity.
In other words, does $\lim(n^2|\sin(n)|)$ exist (equal to infinity)? or there is no such limit?

Comment: That is equivalent to figuring out if $|\pi-\frac pq|<\frac c{q^3}$ has a solution for every $c>0$. The answer is "we don't know yet but we are getting there little by little". Currently the record for the irrationality measure of $\pi$ is 7.606..., way down from Mahler's original 30. So, just wait a couple dozen years :)

Comment: Most people who have thought about this believe we *do* know the answer but, as fedja noted, are still many years from proving it.

Comment: May I humbly suggest that fedja turns her/his comment into an answer, with perhaps some link to where the record is proven?

Comment: Based on fedja's comment, I'm retagging this as an open problem. I also wish John (or someone) would edit this question to "texxify" it. I don't have enough rep yet to edit.

Comment: TeX added, but the question needs editing beyond formatting. Didn't bother with that, since question seems well on its way to closure. 

Comment: I mentioned this specific case in an answer to a math.SE question. http://math.stackexchange.com/a/20609/1321

Comment: @fedja: Is anything more known about this now, 4 years later? =)